# Don't understand why 2D list elements are being given same value

Tags: python, list, 2d

I am trying to deal cards to two hands (each of which is held in a list). The hands are held inside a second list. But player 1's cards are exactly the same as player 2, as if I have a repeating list inside my outer list. Is this because of mutability?

The code snip should help explain. Help! What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**Code**

```
no_of_cards_each = 3
no_of_players = 2
cards = ["AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H"]
player_hands = []

for _ in range(no_of_players):
    player_hands.append([])

print(f"Empty hands = {player_hands}")

for card_num in range(no_of_cards_each):
    print(f"Card Num is {card_num}")
    for player_num in range(no_of_players):
        print(f"Player number is {player_num}")
        next_card = cards.pop(0)
        player_hands[player_num].append(next_card)
        print(f"Player number {player_num} got dealt a {next_card}")

print(f"The final hands look like {player_hands}")
```

**Output**

```
Empty hands = [[], []]
Card Num is 0
Player number is 0
Player number 0 got dealt a AH
Player number is 1
Player number 1 got dealt a 2H
Card Num is 1
Player number is 0
Player number 0 got dealt a 3H
Player number is 1
Player number 1 got dealt a 4H
Card Num is 2
Player number is 0
Player number 0 got dealt a 5H
Player number is 1
Player number 1 got dealt a 6H
```

The final hands look like `[['AH', '3H', '5H'], ['2H', '4H', '6H']]`.

Process finished with exit code 0.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't player one has ['AH', '3H', '5H'], and player 2 has ['2H', '4H', '6H']?
What do you mean by their cards are the same

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Sorry. After struggling this for days, when I reformatted the code to paste the question here it started working as expected. I suppose sometimes just when you have given up is when the code finally starts to work. I should have looked at the result one last time before posting. Sorry to waste your time.

Should I withdraw the question (if possible) or leave it out here? If nothing else, it may be a useful snippet for others facing issues with 2D lists :)